# I get error if i use editText as Double

Tags: string, format, double, decimal

I get error if I use the `editText` field as `Double` value:

```
public void Format1(View view) {
    DecimalFormat num = new DecimalFormat("000.00");

    EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_075_1);
    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_075_1);

    //textView.setText(num.format(1.6789));// works

    textView.setText(num.format(Double.parseDouble(editText.toString()))); // error
```

Comment: can you please share the exact error message!

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: "android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{8322571 VFED..CL. .F...... 416,64-776,256 #7f1001f2 app:id/editText_075_1}"

Comment: what is the input text that you give/

Answer (score 0):

That means, the editText doesn't contain a proper double! So it's better if you check if the edit text is a proper number format before setting it to the textView!

```
boolean checkDouble(String val) {
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(val);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And use it like

```
if(checkDouble(editText.toString())){
    textView.setText(num.format(Double.parseDouble(val)));
}else{
    textView.setText("Please enter a valid double!");
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I get "Please enter a valid double!"
that means this code at this line is not corect :
textView.setText(num.format(Double.parseDouble(val)));

Comment: what was your input!?

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed :
we use Stream and no String
vergot (getText) :

```
editText.getText().toString()) // String : correct
```

editText.getText().toString()) // Stream